# Extend ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

As the title suggests I want to extend the ApiContoller class to include some custom properties and helper methods but whenever I try to use it for a controller I get the message `Multiple actions were found that match the request:`

Example Code:

```
public class ExtendedApiController : ApiController {
    public string SomeHelper() {
    ....
    }
}

public class AccountController : ExtendedApiContoller {
    public void Post (ModelObject obj){
        string x = SomeHelper();
        ...Bunch of business logic
    }
}
```

The Web Api seems to dislike me doing this for some reason or there is some other base method I need to override. The only other option I can see is tacking on extension methods to the ApiContoller but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `[NonAction]` attribute:

```
public class ExtendedApiController : ApiController {

   [NonAction] 
   public string SomeHelper() {
    ....
    }

}
```

More info [here, at the bottom of the page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: That fixed it! I wouldn't have thought it would have matched on the method though as the signature did not conform to the Get/Post/Put/Delete etc.

Answer (score 1):

ASP NET WebAPI uses convention before configuration, so it tries to find a method that begins with `Get...` for GET requests, `Post...` for POST requests and so on for PUT and DELETE.

So maybe you have 2 methods begining by `Get...`, `Post...`, `Put...` or `Delete...`

Comment: No, this is a fresh project and I only have 1 controller so far (besides the ExtendedController). I'm wondering if because the inheritance chain is 3 levels deep that it might be the cause, some internal reflection thats been tripped up.